# Bangkok roof top bar/restaurants recommendations

Tags: thailand, recommendations, bangkok

I am looking for suggestions/recommendations on which roof top bars to go and take some sunset photos in Bangkok. Here are some things I've already researched and found out, which is less than ideal for what I had originally planned.

- I know most are going to require a dress code, and some reservations. I also know most will not just allow anyone up, rather someone eating and drinking (which they are not cheap). I'm ok with this.
- Most roof top bars and restaurants do not allow tripods. I am planning on shooting around sunset and possibly into the evening. So this is going to be tough without a tripod. Also, even if shot during the day I want to do some HDR (I know I can use software in post to align them, but in my experience it's never quite 100%)
- I was also hoping for a roof top restaurant / bar that has a view of the Chao Phraya River
- I am also hoping for a suggestion that is actually open and not a restaurant on a top floor that has windows. It's just one more obstacle.

What I'm seeking just simply might not exist. Just thought I would check with the community. Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry but we don't do recommendations -- they're very much a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: [**Banyan Tree Bangkok**](https://goo.gl/maps/Vjaf6iqmozLewYYc9) has two nice bars at floor 52 and 65 that fit some of the above requirements (no dress code and filming is allowed)

Answer (score 3):

**[Sirocco](http://www.lebua.com/sirocco)** atop the Lebua Hotel and **[Vertigo/Moon Bar](http://www.banyantree.com/en/ap-thailand-bangkok/vertigo-and-moon-bar)** atop the Banyan Tree should check all your boxes except the tripod ban.  They're bars, so reservations are not required and you can get away with just one (expensive!) drink, although depending on time/day cover charges may apply.  A minimal dress code applies (no sandals, no shorts), but you don't need to rent a tuxedo.  And they're both near the river and fully open air, with no glass walls etc.

The tripod rule, though, is going to be difficult: this is usually assumed to mean commercial photography.  You can ask ahead of time, or just bring along of those small, cheap portable ones and plead ignorance in the unlikely event of anybody raising a fuss.

Answer (score 2):

The staff at Zoom SkyBar, Anantara Sathorn, is quite cool. You might get away with a tripod for a short while if you communicate with them ahead of time. The view is very nice. 360° view of Bangkok.

Another place with a great view is the Scarlett bar  restaurant at Pullman G, Silom. If you're a guest at the hotel, you can pretty much get the run of the place if you make friends with the staff -- especially the [farang] managing staff (they love to have good reviews on TripAdvisor, wink wink hint hint).

Another hotel with a slightly more restricted view is the Novotel Ploenchit, on Sukhumvit. The executive lounge is on the top floor (29th) has an outdoor area that is seldom used. Again, if you're a guest there, you get pretty much the run of the place, and the ladies running the lounge are super friendly.

Comment: Scarlett bar looks like it might give me the view I'm looking for. Mostly a good city scape with a view of the Chao Phraya River. I'm checking around online to try and find out more. It looks like it may be an indoor restaurant with glass windows? Can you help me confirm either way? Thanks.

Comment: It's an indoor restaurant with an outdoor terrace. The terrace is full quickly unless the weather discourages people. But the sun sets early here, so you could come ahead of the crowd. Also, Thursdays are bustling and Fridays are dead, so you could schedule your shoot on a Friday.